# How to paginate query results using Laravel and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, pagination

I'm trying to convert this static query

```
$companiesFinal = Websites::query();

    if(!empty($request->searchWord)) {
        $companiesFinal->where('web_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->searchWord . '%');
        $companiesFinal->where('web_seo_url', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->searchWord . '%');
    }

    if(!empty($request->category)){
        if(is_array($request->category)) {
            foreach($request->category as $categ) {
                $companiesFinal->orWhere('web_category', 'LIKE', '%' . $categ . '%');
            }
        } else {
            $companiesFinal->where('web_category', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->category . '%');
        }
    }

    if(!empty($request->claimed)){
        if($request->claimed == "all") {} else {
            $companiesFinal->where('claimed', '=', $request->claimed);
        }
    }

    if(!empty($request->sortBy)) {
        if($request->sortBy == "newest") {
            $companiesFinal->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
        } elseif($request->sortBy == "oldest") {
            $companiesFinal->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC');
        }
    }

    $companies = $companiesFinal->paginate(7);
}
```

to an AJAX jQuery call, and here comes the confusing part. I've already tried to do that but unsuccessful.

I tried something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '{{ url("/ajaxCall") }}',
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
        var websites = "";
        $.each(response.data, function(index, value) {
            websites = websites + "<div>... " + value.web_name + "......." + value.web_link + "...</div>";
        });
        $(".getResults").html(websites);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
    }
});
```

of course when I tried that I've converted the controller query to return a JSON response, and other necessary stuff, but the result was the browser console saying "value not defined".

Also confusing for me is how I am gonna display Laravel pagination when getting this data with Ajax? I'll be so grateful if someone helps.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What debugging have you tried?  In your browser's devtools, if you click on the network tab, is the expected `data` being sent to the server with your request?  How about the response - does it look like what you expect?  "*I've converted the controller query to return json response*" - you didn't show us that part ...?  Your AJAX code doesn't include a `dataType` - if all goes well that's not required, but all is not going well, so ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, the data structure returned from Laravel when you use [pagination into a JSON result](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#converting-results-to-json) looks like this:

```
{
   "total": 50,
   "per_page": 15,
   "current_page": 1,
   "last_page": 4,
   "first_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=1",
   "last_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=4",
   "next_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=2",
   "prev_page_url": null,
   "path": "http://laravel.app",
   "from": 1,
   "to": 15,
   "data":[
        {
            // Record...
        },
        {
            // Record...
        }
   ]
}
```

So assuming this HTML structure:

```
<form>
  <!-- your search form ... --->
</form>
<div id="getResults"></div>
<div id="pages"></div>
```

I would use this kind of JavaScript:

```
function searchUrl(page) {
  return '{{ url("/ajaxCall") }}?' + $("form").serialize() + '&page=' + page;
}

function showResult(page) {
  return $.get(searchUrl(page)).done(function (result) {
    // render result records
    $("#getResults").empty();
    result.data.forEach(function (record) {
      $("<div>... " + record.web_name + "......." + record.web_link + "...</div>").appendTo("#getResults");
    });

    // render pagination links
    $("#pages").empty();
    for (let p = 1; p <= result.last_page; p++) {
      if (p === result.current_page) $('<span>' + p + '</span>').appendTo("#pages");
      else $('<a href="' + searchUrl(p) + '">' + p + '</a>').appendTo("#pages");
    }
  }).fail(function(xhr, status, thrownError) {
    console.error(xhr.status, thrownError);
  });
}

$(function () {
  $("form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    showResult(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `result.data.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Also following your script why do we use `showResult(1);` on document load and not `showResult('{{ url("AJAXPAGE") }}');`

Comment: @JohnFurgeson The code above was not meant to be copied. The code above was meant to be studied and then adapted to your needs. I have no idea what `result` is in your case - your sever sends something, and you have never showed it. I'm making assumptions from the documentation. Set a breakpoint in your browser's developer tools, look at the data you actually get, and make the necessary changes.

Comment: *"why do we use `showResult(1);` on document load and not `showResult('{{ url("AJAXPAGE") }}')`"* - That's not on document load. That's on form submit. You want to load page #1 when the user clicks `Search`.

Comment: I totally understand the code except that how do I handle the result in the `function()` brackets. When I open the URL where the query is based I'm getting the results I expect. But how do I handle them in the function brackets?

Comment: @JohnFurgeson I'm not sure what you mean by "in function brackes"? Also I still don't know what results you are getting. It's nice that they are what you expect, but that does not tell *me* anything. ;)

Comment: In this case with your code for example what role should the **result** playing? Is that an array with the whole JSON result and I handle the information needed for example with **result.data.id** for each record or what? That's what I actually asked.

Comment: @JohnFurgeson If everything is set up correctly on your server side, `result` should be a data structure exactly like the one on shown top of my answer. But I can't say what your server actually returns. You need to look into the browser's developer tools and find out for yourself.

Comment: The server returns literally a data structure like the one on the top of your answer.

Comment: @JohnFurgeson Then my answer should work as-is. What's the `Content-Type` of the server's response?

Comment: Also when I replace the `result.data.foreach` with `$.each` I'm still getting `**ExampleVar** is null` but atleast I'm getting 6 `...undefined...` which means it's getting the data right from the DB, because there are only 6 records in it.

Comment: **Content-Type application/json** of course.

Comment: @JohnFurgeson OK, `application/json` is correct. It could have been `text/html`, that's a common source of issues. But overall, interactive debugging in the comments here is not effective. I can't see what you're seeing, and all I can say is that my code above will work if the data structure you get actually looks like expected. Somewhere you are making a mistake, or a wrong assumption. Set a breakpoint on `$("#getResults").empty();`, step through the code line by line, look at every variable, think it through.

Comment: Got a solution. Your code works perfect, it was my bad. But there's another problem. I need to get a image path from the database with this code but also use the Laravel function **asset()** to get the actual path to it so I can display it in **<img>** tag. When i try **asset(" ' +  record.image_path + ' ")** I'm actually getting the following result in the **<img>** tag: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/logos/logo.png`. Same with other Laravel functions like **Str::words()** etc... What should I do?

Comment: @JohnFurgeson *"What should I do?"* - Mark this answer as accepted (as it addresses the question and you can confirm that it works), which will mark this thread as solved, and open a new question that *only* focuses on the part of how to get the expected img src URL out of Laravel. :)